# How to limit shell script execution time?

Tags: shell, cron, cron-task

I have a scheduled cron job (which is actually a shell script). I'd like to limit the script execution time as it can work unacceptably long. For some reason I can not limit the script execution time from inside the script. Actually, I want my system to force the task termination if it runs more than N hours. Please advise.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387485/limiting-the-time-a-program-runs-in-linux

Comment: See [Can I limit the runtime of a cronjob](http://serverfault.com/a/257347) over at serverfault.com.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm responding by myself just because none answered.

```
0 * * * * timeout -s 9 3540 /path/to/your_command.sh
```

will send a SIGINT to your command if it hasn't completed in 59 minutes.

Comment: not works at me `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/timeout -s 9 60 && cd /usr/etc && python2.6 hello.py 10.10.252.120 437 >> res.txt
`

Answer (score 8):

Using an -s 9 is a little extreme as it doesn't let the process do any cleanup.  Yes, it will kill the process if it can be killed, but > 90% of the time a -s 1, which requests a graceful hangup, will suffice.

Comment: kill -9 should always be the last resort!